# how testing association in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, rspec2

please help testing association. i have models:

```
class Album < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :albums, dependent: :destroy
end
```

i try testing association:

```
describe Album do
  describe 'associations' do
     it "belongs_to user" do
        should belongs_to(:user)
     end
  end  
end
```

after run test in console, i get follow:

> Failures:   1) Album associations belongs_to user
>        Failure/Error: should belongs_to(:user)
>        NoMethodError:
>          undefined method `belongs_to' for #<RSpec::ExampleGroups::Album::Associations:0x0000000762bc98>
>        # ./spec/models/album_spec.rb:36:in`block (3 levels) in '
>
> Finished in 1.41 seconds (files took 2.32 seconds to load) 7 examples,
>   1 failure Failed examples: rspec ./spec/models/album_spec.rb:35 #
>   Album associations belongs_to user

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can test this association easily using `belong_to` matcher of the gem [shoulda](https://github.com/thoughtbot/shoulda):

```
describe Album do
  it { should belong_to(:user) }
end
```

See [this for an example](https://github.com/thoughtbot/shoulda#rspec-with-shoulda-matchers).